# Sort on each SQL Server query not working when used with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have to merge data from 3 different tables which have different columns and my desired output should be based on different sort condition of each table.

I am using this query below but this query sort the overall result on based on Menu Position, How can I change this query to sort the result on individual query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     PID, MENU, Handler, PageLangID, ParentID, IssueID, CatID, MenuPosition 
FROM (
   --Pages Table 
   SELECT TOP 50 
       PageId AS PID,SUBSTRING(PageName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, PageLangID,PageInheritance AS ParentID, 1 AS IssueID, 1 AS CatID, 
        PageLinkPosition as MenuPosition  FROM pg_Pages  WHERE PageLangID = 1  ORDER BY PageLinkPosition DESC 
UNION 
--Article Category Table
SELECT TOP 20 p.PageID AS PID, SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, 
c.LangID,p.PageID,1, ArticleCategoryID, 1 AS MenuPosition FROM art_Category c JOIN pg_Pages p 
ON c.PageID = p.PageID  JOIN art_CategoryType ct ON c.Type = ct.CategoryTypeID WHERE c.LangID =1  AND c.Type =1 
ORDER BY c.ArticleCategoryName  
UNION 
--Magazine Table
SELECT TOP 10 p.PageID AS PID, CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10)),SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler,LangID,p.PageID AS ParentID, m.IssueID AS IssueID, 1, 
       1 AS MenuPosition FROM Magazine m   JOIN pg_pages p ON m.PageID = p.PageID   WHERE LangID =1  ORDER BY 2 DESC  
) AS T  WHERE T.PageLangID = 1 ORDER BY MenuPosition
```

**Second Way**

If I use below query then I get following error

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
>
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.*

**QUERY**

```
--Pages Table 
SELECT TOP 50 PageId AS PID,SUBSTRING(PageName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, PageLangID,PageInheritance AS ParentID, 1 AS IssueID, 1 AS CatID, 
        PageLinkPosition as MenuPosition  FROM pg_Pages  WHERE PageLangID = 1  ORDER BY PageLinkPosition DESC 
UNION 
--Article Category Table
SELECT TOP 20 p.PageID AS PID, SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, 
c.LangID,p.PageID,1, ArticleCategoryID, 1 AS MenuPosition FROM art_Category c JOIN pg_Pages p 
ON c.PageID = p.PageID  JOIN art_CategoryType ct ON c.Type = ct.CategoryTypeID WHERE c.LangID =1  AND c.Type =1 
ORDER BY c.ArticleCategoryName  ASC
UNION 
--Magazine Table
SELECT TOP 10 p.PageID AS PID, CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10)),SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler,LangID,p.PageID AS ParentID, m.IssueID AS IssueID, 1, 
       1 AS MenuPosition FROM Magazine m   JOIN pg_pages p ON m.PageID = p.PageID   WHERE LangID =1  ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
PID         MENU                 Handler                  PageLangID  ParentID    IssueID     CatID       MenuPosition
----------- -------------------- ------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
6           Book Review          Page.aspx                1           6           1           18          1
6           Business             Page.aspx                1           6           1           16          1
6           Culture              Page.aspx                1           6           1           3           1
6           Economy              Page.aspx                1           6           1           2           1
6           Finance              Page.aspx                1           6           1           19          1
6           Infrastructure       Page.aspx                1           6           1           17          1
6           Lifestyle            Page.aspx                1           6           1           20          1
6           Others               Page.aspx                1           6           1           21          1
6           People               Page.aspx                1           6           1           7           1
6           Politics             Page.aspx                1           6           1           1           1
6           Sports               Page.aspx                1           6           1           4           1
12          102                  Page.aspx                1           12          3           1           1
12          103                  Page.aspx                1           12          4           1           1
12          106                  Page.aspx                1           12          1           1           1
12          109                  Page.aspx                1           12          5           1           1
1           Home                 Default.aspx             1           0           1           1           10
11          Video                Videos.aspx              1           10          1           1           10
2           About Us             Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           20
5           Articles             Articles.aspx            1           0           1           1           30
6           Categories           Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           40
12          Archive              Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           50
3           News                 News.aspx                1           0           1           1           60
10          Multimedia           Multimedia.aspx          1           0           1           1           70
```

I want first query to sort by `ORDER BY PageLinkPosition DESC`

Second query to sort by `ORDER BY c.ArticleCategoryName  ASC`

and third query to sort by `ORDER BY IssueCode DESC`

I tried so many way but could not get it work properly.

Appreciate help in this regard

**UPDATE**: Working Query based on Mark Solution with small changes

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID, MENU, Handler, PageLangID, ParentID, IssueID, CatID, MenuPosition, block, rNum
FROM    
(   --Pages Table 
    SELECT TOP 50 
        PageId AS PID,SUBSTRING(PageName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, PageLangID,PageInheritance AS ParentID, 1 AS IssueID, 1 AS CatID, 
        PageLinkPosition as MenuPosition
        ,Block = 1
        ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PageLinkPosition DESC)  
    FROM pg_Pages  
    WHERE PageLangID = 1  
    UNION ALL   -- Better to UNION ALL and then DISTINCT outside
--Article Category Table
    SELECT TOP 20 
        p.PageID AS PID, SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, 
        c.LangID,p.PageID,1, ArticleCategoryID, 1 AS MenuPosition
        ,Block = 2 
        ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.ArticleCategoryName )
    FROM art_Category c 
    JOIN pg_Pages p             ON c.PageID = p.PageID  
    JOIN art_CategoryType ct    ON c.Type = ct.CategoryTypeID 
    WHERE c.LangID =1  AND c.Type =1 
    UNION ALL
--Magazine Table
    SELECT TOP 10 p.PageID AS PID, CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10)),SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler,LangID,p.PageID AS ParentID, m.IssueID AS IssueID, 1, 
       1 AS MenuPosition
       ,Block = 3 
       ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10))DESC)
    FROM Magazine m   
    JOIN pg_pages p ON m.PageID = p.PageID   
    WHERE LangID =1  
) AS T  WHERE T.PageLangID = 1 
ORDER BY Block, rNum
```

MARK Later update his solution to CTE version please check his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work;

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 50 
         PageId AS PID
        ,SUBSTRING(PageName,0,20) AS MENU
        ,SUBSTRING(PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler
        ,PageLangID
        ,PageInheritance AS ParentID
        ,1 AS IssueID
        ,1 AS CatID
        ,PageLinkPosition as MenuPosition
        ,Block = 1
        ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PageLinkPosition DESC)  
    FROM pg_Pages  
    WHERE PageLangID = 1  
    UNION ALL   
--Article Category Table
    SELECT TOP 20 
         p.PageID AS PID
        ,SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU
        ,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler
        ,c.LangID
        ,p.PageID
        ,1
        ,ArticleCategoryID
        ,1 AS MenuPosition
        ,Block = 2 
        ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.ArticleCategoryName )
    FROM art_Category c 
    JOIN pg_Pages p             ON c.PageID = p.PageID  
    JOIN art_CategoryType ct    ON c.Type = ct.CategoryTypeID 
    WHERE c.LangID =1  AND c.Type =1 
    UNION ALL
--Magazine Table
    SELECT TOP 10 
         p.PageID AS PID
        ,CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10))
        ,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler
        ,LangID
        ,p.PageID AS ParentID
        ,m.IssueID AS IssueID
        ,1
        ,1 AS MenuPosition
        ,Block = 3 
        ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10)))
    FROM Magazine m   
    JOIN pg_pages p ON m.PageID = p.PageID   
    WHERE LangID =1  
)
,Deduplicate AS
(
    SELECT   PID
            ,MENU
            ,Handler
            ,PageLangID
            ,ParentID
            ,IssueID
            ,CatID
            ,MenuPosition 
            ,Block
            ,rNum
            ,Occ = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID, MENU, Handler, PageLangID, ParentID, IssueID, CatID, MenuPosition ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT  PID
       ,MENU
       ,Handler
       ,PageLangID
       ,ParentID
       ,IssueID
       ,CatID
       ,MenuPosition 
FROM Deduplicate
WHERE Occ = 1
ORDER BY Block, rNum
```

Comment: I get this error `Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: If i ignore Order by clause then it get result & obviously not as desired. last part of query generate error `ORDER BY Block, rNum`

Comment: I've removed the outer `DISTINCT` and used `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. What error are you getting now?

Comment: I made it work by adding in SELECT part of first line  `Block, rNum` and made small change to by adding Sort type ASC OR DESC to get desired result.. I am still testing it.. ++UPDATE++ `ORDER BY CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10))DESC

Comment: I've made another change, would you try it and let me know?

Comment: CTE this is what i was looking in first place.. It is working, Could you please tell me which one should i use from performance point of view. I will mark your solution correct anyway as both the queries work.

Comment: Its difficult for me to be certain without data to test with and having no indexes for your tables. But, given your requirements, I think this will perform quite well with the right indexes. Perhaps someone with a deeper knowledge could offer some comments.

Comment: I checked the execution plan, their is not much difference as amount of data retrieved wont be more than 50 row and wont need to sort check more than 100 row. Thanks for you help